# How do I import packages in Java?

Tags: java, import, package

I have a "Sprites" folder with some class files and a "Launcher" folder with some class files. I tried the following code for import:

```
package Sprites;
```

and it lead to the following

```
hw9\Launcher>javac *.java
TowerDefense.java:2: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package Sprites;
^
1 error
```

Am I doing this incorrectly? My Sprites and Launcher are in the hw9 directory, so I assumed it would work. A picture for clarification:
[image]

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions, make sure your packages are named with only lowercase letters.

Comment: I changed it to lower-case and tried import sprites.*, but I'm getting an error that states that "package sprites does not exist". I'm a little confused because they are both in the same directory.

Comment: Packages should be in the directory they are named after - please see read about the [Java folder structure](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/packages.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a wildcard import to import all classes within the immediate directory:

```
import Sprites.*;
```

This opposed to something like:

```
import Sprites.Class1;
import Sprites.Class2;
import Sprites.Class3;
...
```

---

Generally, wildcard imports can produce conflicts and errors (for example `java.awt.List` and `java.util.List`), so usually better to avoid them.

Packages should also be lower-cased.

Comment: I'm getting an error that states that package sprites does that exist after doing the import sprites.*;

Comment: @Shan the package names are case sensitive and are reflective of actual directories. Make sure the existing directory is spelled the same as how you reference it in the code. If you're using an IDE, you can request it to provide the correct imports, that way you can verify that those classes are on the classpath.

Comment: I renamed it so it was lower-case, and made the adjustment. I don't think I'm using an IDE so unfortunately I can't verify. I tried to move my "sprites" folder out of the hw9 directory but it looks like that isn't working either.

Comment: @Shan that location should be fine. Is the `hw9` folder a package as well?

Comment: I don't believe so. hw9 is just a directory that includes "Sprites" and "Launcher". I can provide a picture for clarification

Comment: @Shan that would be great. You should be then compiling within the `hw9` folder as well, right?

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to syntax, usually when you see something like `...expected` that is syntax error indicator.

In the class in your launcher package, include the `import` statements for the classes which are being referred to.

It should look something like the following:

```
package the.name.of.your.package;
import Spirites.NameOfclass; //quialify the import parth as is
class YourLauncherClass{ 
//class definition 
}
```

Also make sure that semicolons aren't missing at the end of import and package.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to import the specific class you require rather than importing the complete package.

```
import Spirites.NameOfclassRequired; 
class YourClass{ 
//class definition 
}
```

If you are using eclipse you can do that using `CTRL+SHIFT+O` When you do that eclipse imports the specific class you require. For an instance if you using an ArrayList rather than importing `java.util.*;` it will import `java.util.ArrayList;`

If you need multiple classes from a package then for sure you can import the entire package